# SUMO Simulaiton in CLI using python returns "Permission Error/Access is Denied"

Tags: python, sumo

I am trying to run a simple simulation using Eclips SUMO CLI in python, but every time it returns permission error and access is denied. this simulation runs perfectly in macOS but Windows 11, python 3.11 is creating this issue. I attach a picture of error codes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPNkj.png)
Please help me solving the problem. Thanks a lot.

Code:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
from shapely import wkt,geometry
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Polygon
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import sumolib

def run_sumo_simulation(config_file, output_dir):
    # Build the SUMO command
    sumo_binary = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo'  # Set the correct path to your SUMO binary
    command = [sumo_binary, "-c", config_file, "--output-prefix", os.path.join(output_dir, "output")]

    # Run the SUMO simulation
    try:
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        print("Simulation completed successfully.")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print("Error occurred while running the simulation.")

def main():
    # Set the paths to your configuration files
    sumo_config_file = "sumo_config.sumocfg"
    
    # Set the output directory for simulation results
    output_directory = "os.getcwd()"
    os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

    # Run the SUMO simulation
    run_sumo_simulation(sumo_config_file, output_directory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Which line is the error? Creating `output_directory`, using `output_directory` or some other place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got following error:

Comment: OK, so the traceback shows there is an issue with this line `subprocess.run(command, check=True)` and checking that line shows that the path `os.path.join(output_dir, "output")` is incorrect. Checking further, in the main function you have the line   `output_directory = "os.getcwd()"` which means that `output_directory` is given the string value `os.getcwd()` not the 'current working directory' because `os.getcwd()` is in double quotes. Remove the double quotes so the line is `output_directory = os.getcwd()` and it will provide the actual current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Just repeating the comment above by @moken which contains the correct answer I believe:

In the main function you have the line `output_directory = "os.getcwd()"` which means that output_directory is given the string value `os.getcwd()` not the 'current working directory' because os.getcwd() is in double quotes. Remove the double quotes so the line is `output_directory = os.getcwd()` and it will provide the actual current working directory.

This code may "work" on macOS in the sense that it does not raise an exception but it will still not produce sensible results.